# Passing values between functions

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

Hi All is there any way to locally define a variable in a function and then pass it to the oher function. I mean to say is it possible the pass a local value  from one function to other function.
Somebody Please suggest me the solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or it's that simple or you meant something else:

```
private function function1():void
{
    var localVariable:String = "this is local variable of function1()";
    function2(localVariable);
}

private function function2(string:String):void
{
    trace(string);
}

function1();
```

or use global variable as temporary storage:

```
private var globalVariable:String = "";

private function function1():void
{
    var localVariable:String = "this is local variable of function1()";

    globalVariable = localVariable;
}

private function function2():void
{
    trace(globalVariable);
}

function1();
function2();
```

Comment: Hi zdmytriv,
Yes thats what i was wanted as a solution..Thanks a ton.!!

Answer (score 2):

zdmytriv is right.

Although, you can also make default variables, like so:

(Modifying zdmytriv's code)

```
private function function1():void
{
    var localVariable:String = "this is local variable of function1()";
    function2(localVariable);
    function2(); //You don't have to enter a default argument
}

private function function2(string:String = "something else"):void
{
    trace(string);
}
```

This would trace:

```
this is local variable of function1()
something else
```

A little off topic, but good to know.

Comment: Thanx pipeep for such a nic explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Primitives in Flex are passed by value, where complex objects are passed by reference. You can use this to pass objects around without scoping a variable outside the functions themselves. For instance:

```
private function function1():void {
{
     var localVar:Object = {value:"test"};
     trace(localVar.value);
     function2(localVar);
     trace(localVar.value);
}

private function function2(obj:Object):void
{
     obj.value = "new value";
}
```

This would trace:

```
test
new value
```

Which reflects the fact that function2 receives the parameter "obj" by reference, as a pointer to the original "localVar" object. When it sets the .value field, that change is reflected in function1.

I just thought I'd point that out.